# How do I save a track on map in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, geolocation, location

How do I save the data of a track travelled with lat and lon values for each second, in MySQL database?
There will be a set of latitude and longitude for each second, and if I have tracked the movement of a person for say a minute, there will be 60 sets of these values that make up the track.
I need to save this track to MySQL database so that the user can see the track  travelled in the future.
What datatype should I use for this?

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to create a table of `INT, DOUBLE, DOUBLE` and storing the second# in the `INT`, and use the `DOUBLEs` to store latitude and longitude. Then you can retrieve the table, use an `ORDER BY` to put them in order, and work with the locations from there.

Another way to do this would be to use the [spacial information extensions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/spatial-extensions.html)

Comment: thanks for the quick reply @FSQ but wouldn't that be a problem when the user saves many such tracks and the database table would be flooded with values?

Comment: It would. One way to get around that is to have a different table for each track, with the names of each table structured in a predictable manner, i.e. username_track1. That way, the tables remain smallish yet easily accessible. There isn't really a way to store a track in any manner more compact than a series of points in a database; at least, not as far as I know.